# How do calculate a measure of how closely a value is to unknown groups defined in a set?

Tags: statistics

I have a set of points. Within this set, I expect that there are a number of distinct groups. For example, the plot below would be representative of the type of set I am referring to:
[image: y axis is data value, x data index]
In the chart, there are two distinct groups. I would now like to estimate how similar a given value is to the group that it most likely belongs to. For example, one measure would be the absolute difference between the point and the mean of the group.

My question is, how can a mathematically identify the groups (if any) that exist within a set?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for a **clustering** method, e.g., the [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) clustering.

Comment: Comment not Answer.

Comment: Sorta. kMeans is overkill for this applications. CKmeans is more appropriate. However, as I understand ckmeans, it requires a known number of classes. In the dataset I am presented with, the number of classes is unknown.